# Running external program using pipes and passing arguments in python

Tags: python

I am running an external program using pipes in python and it works fine. However I would like to pass two arguments to this external program.

Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['external-program', 'arg1', 'arg2'], 
                stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

if you mean piping the out into or out of the Python script, or

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('external-program arg1 arg2 | external2'], shell=True)
```

if you mean piping output between external programs.

See the [subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). Post your code if you want a different type of solution.

Comment: If he's actually using pipes between external programs you do. It's not clear from the question whether the pipes were between Python and the external program or what.

Comment: The only time you need `shell=True` is when you are on windows and you need to call commands that are cooked into `cmd.exe`

Comment: so you're saying `'cat file1 | grep "glob"'` would work without `shell=True`? What would interpret the pipe?

Comment: Why would you pipe inside the subprocess and rather not redirect the output in python.

Comment: I'm not saying it's _advisable_, I'm saying it might be what he's doing now. I've edited my answer to split it up into two parts.

Comment: If only I hadn't hit the rep cap hours ago :)

Comment: @agf let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2286/discussion-between-jakob-bowyer-and-agf)

Comment: Thank you agf and all! That actually worked. My both scripts are written in python. One needs to run the other one and pass two arguments, which are then used to select data from the database, etc. I still don't know how to read these arguments in the other script to use them further. Could I get help on that as well? I've seen documentation for that, but it's still hard to understand docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen Sorry for my lack of knowledge on Python, but I am just learning it and it's tough! :) Great thanks for your help tho!

Comment: The arguments are stored in `sys.argv` so just do `import sys` then `ag1 = argv[1]` and `arg2 = argv[2]`. `argv[0]` is the name of the script. If you need more help on it, post another question. Please click the check mark next to my answer to accept it if it solved your original problem.

Comment: That's completely unreadable. Either edit it in to your question, properly formatted, or ask a new question.