# Passing argument to constantly running Python application

Tags: python

I have a constantly running Python code on Linux, every so often outside data needs to be fed into this code so Python code can alter a file. 
How do I go about structuring Python code so it receives these arguments for further processing?

I found some stuff on outgoing args, [Running external program using pipes and passing arguments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998955/running-external-program-using-pipes-and-passing-arguments-in-python)

But looking for in coming args

Flexible with how arguments get passed down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some kind of Inter Process Communication.

For example, you can feed program's standard input. You can read it by reading from `sys.stdin`, but it requires the program that started your process to give its handle to another process.

Another way is to create a [socket](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) of some kind. That's far more scalable, allows connecting to the program when it's running on another machine, and allows non-Python processes to easily communicate with your process.